# Quick question regarding CSS sprites and memory usage

Tags: html, css

Well, it's more to do with images and memory in general.  If I use the same image multiple times on a page, will each image be consolidated in memory?  Or will each image use a separate amount of memory?

I'm concerned about this because I'm building a skinning system for a Windows Desktop Gadget, and I'm looking at spriting the images in the default skin so that I can keep the file system looking clean.  At the same time I want to try and keep the memory footprint to a minimum.  If I end up with a single file containing 100 images and re-use that image 100 times across the gadget I don't want to have performance issues.

Cheers.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What about testing it? Create a simple application with and without spriting, and monitor your windows memory to see which approach is better.

I'm telling you to test it because of this [interesting post from Vladimir](http://blog.vlad1.com/2009/06/22/to-sprite-or-not-to-sprite/), even endorsed by [Mozilla "use sprites wisely"](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/06/22/use-sprites-wisely/) entry:

> (...) where this image is used as a sprite.  Note that this is a 1299x15,000 PNG.
>   It compresses quite well — the actual download size is around 26K - but browsers 
>   don't render compressed image data.  When this image is downloaded and 
>   decompressed, it will use almost **75MB** in memory (1299 * 15000 * 4).

(At the end of Vladimir's post there are some other great references to check)

Since I don't know how Windows renders it's gadgets (and if it's not going to handle compressed image data), it's dificult IMHO to say exactly which approach is better without testing.

**EDIT:** The official [Windows Desktop blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/sidebar/) (not updated since 2007) says [the HTML runtime used for Windows Gadgets is MSHTML](http://blogs.msdn.com/sidebar/default.aspx?p=2), so I think a test is really needed to know how your application would handle the CSS sprites.

However, if you read some of the official [Windows Desktop Gadgets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd834142.aspx) and [Windows sidebar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965850(VS.85).aspx) documentation, there's an interesting thing about your decision to **not use** css sprites, in the [The GIMAGE Protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb676240(VS.85).aspx) section:

> This protocol is useful for adding
>   images to the gadget DOM more
>   efficiently than the standard HTML
>    tag. This efficiency results
>   from improved thumbnail handling and
>   image caching (it will attempt to use
>   thumbnails from the Windows cache if
>   the requested size is smaller than 256
>   pixels by 256 pixels) when compared
>   with requesting an image using the
>   file:// or http:// protocols. An added
>   benefit of the gimage protocol is that
>   any file other than a standard image
>   file can be specified as a source, and
>   the icon associated with that file's
>   type is displayed.

I would try to use this protocol instead of CSS sprites and do some testing too.

If none of this information would help you, I would try to ask at [Windows Desktop Gadgets official forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sidebargadfetdevelopment/threads).

Good luck!

Comment: I was hoping to avoid testing it, I thought it might be rather time consuming.  It's definitely an option though.  +1 for a great link, it explained a lot and might even have answered my question.

Comment: @GmonC: re: your edit, suggesting the g:image protocol would be a great idea if it were only that easy.  Unfortunately, it's a relatively buggy implemenation, some images can appear blurry when using them and it's difficult to get images at the size you want.

Comment: Congratulations on your bounty - you earned it.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I hope you can succeed in your tests. I would do some search to see if Windows Gadgets are *really* being used to know if it's worth to spend time on it (I've even disabled my sidebar for example!), specially when you said that an official microsoft protocol (is even recommended in the docs) is buggy.

Answer (score 5):

The image will show up one time in the cache (as long as the url is the same and there's no query string appended to the file name). Spriting is the way to go.

Comment: Are you referring to file-system caching? If so, that doesn't really apply to Windows Desktop Gadgets as they run on the local file system anyway.  Memory usage is my main concern.

Comment: I meant the browser cache. From what I can tell, Windows Desktop Gadgets uses HTML/CSS/JavaScript/etc. I'd be extremely surprised if it worked differently for gadgets.

I was thinking of a web-hosted gadget, in your case spriting wouldn't be necessary, it'd probably be easier to organize things with individual image files.

Comment: I was actually just thinking about spriting hover/focus images, to keep the skins folders a bit tidier.  At the same time I thought, why not sprite them all, background images, etc?  Just thought it would be simpler to have a single file for each group of images rather than all images individual.  Hence my question regarding memory/performance.

Answer (score 1):

Webbrowsers identifies cacheable resources by their [`ETag`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19) response header. If it is absent or differs among requests, then the image may be downloaded and stored in cache multiple times. If you (actually, the webserver) supply an unique and the same `ETag` header for each unique resource, then any decent webbrowser is smart enough to keep one in cache and reuse it as long as its [`Expires`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) header allows.

Any decent webserver will supply the `ETag` header automatically for static resources, it is often autogenerated based on a combination of the local filename, the file length and the last modified timestamp. But often they don't add the `Expires` header, so you need to add it yourself. After judging your post history here at Stackoverflow I safely assume that you're familiar with Apache HTTPD as web server, so I'd suggest to have a look at [`mod_expires` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html) to learn how to configure it yourself to an optimum.

In a nutshell, serve the sprite image along with an `ETag` and a far future `Expires` header and it'll be okay.